# How to compare keys in a hash table with the values of an Array (stored in another Hash table)?

Tags: perl, hashtable

I want to create a "complex" data structure from two text files.

The first file has an English sentence, a French sentence, and a score on each line. For example

```
The cat eats the mouse # Le chat mange la souris # 2.8
```

I've had no problems using the following code to populate a hash from the file. The keys are the English sentences.

```
my $hash = { };

while ( my $text = <TEXT> ) {
  if ( $text =~ /(^(.+)#(.+)#(.+)$)/ ) {

    my $english_sentence = $2;
    my $french_sentence  = $3;
    my $score            = $4;

    $hash->{$english_sentence}->{translation} = $french_sentence;
    $hash->{$english_sentence}->{score}       = $score;
    my @words_en = split(/ /, $english_sentence);
    $hash->{$english_sentence}->{tokens_en} = \@words_en;

  }
  else {
    print "No sentences find in the input document" . "\n";
  }
}
```

The resultant hash looks like this

```
$VAR1 = {
  'The cat eats the mouse' => {
    'words_en'    => ['The', 'cat', 'eats', 'the', 'mouse'],
    'score'       => '2.8',
    'translation' => 'Le chat mange la souris'
  }
};
```

The second file has translations of English words

```
   cat ||| chat ||| 0.600000 
   cat ||| félin ||| 0.500000
   eats ||| mange ||| 0.500000
   eats ||| manger ||| 0.500000
   mouse ||| souris ||| 0.600000 
   mouse ||| rat ||| 0.500000
```

The resultant hash looks like this:

```
$VAR1 = {
  'eats' => {
      'manger' => '0.500000',
      'mange' => '0.600000'
   },
  'cat' => {
      "félin" => '0.500000',
      'chat' => '0.600000 '
  },
  'mouse' => {
      'souris' => '0.600000 ',
      'rat' => '0.500000'
  }
};
```

Now i need to compare each value of the array stored in the first Hash:

```
words_en'    => ['The', 'cat', 'eats', 'the', 'mouse']
```

with the keys of the second hash.

Finally, I want to print a thing like that:

```
The cat[chat;félin] eats[mange;manger] the souris[souris;rat] # Le chat mange la souris # 2.8
```

Comment: I have altered your post to make it clearer. I haven't changed your Perl code at all except to add or remove insignificant white space. Your choice of data structure seems reasonable, but we can't know whether it's appropriate for your application unless you explain what this data is for. If you described your final application, and how this data is relevant, then I am sure that we would be able to help you.

Comment: I've updated the post. I've now created two Hashes and I try to compare them, in order to obtain a specific output foreach sentences.

Comment: Where'd the dog come into it?

Comment: Sorry just a mistake - I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to quickly perform some of the operations you need, there are additional operators in [List::MoreUtils](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils) that can help you do more with these types of data structures.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words_en = ('The', 'cat', 'eats', 'the', 'mouse');
my $conversion  = {
  'eats' => {
      'manger' => '0.500000',
      'mange' => '0.600000'
   },
  'cat' => {
      "félin" => '0.500000',
      'chat' => '0.600000 '
  },
  'mouse' => {
      'souris' => '0.600000 ',
      'rat' => '0.500000'
  }
};

# Creates corresponding translation to your @words_en data
my @translations = map { [ keys ( $conversion->{$_} || {} ) ] }   @words_en  ;

# Print in the suggested format
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar @words_en; $i++) {
  print $words_en[$i];
  print '[' . join(';', @{ $translations[$i] } ) . ']' if scalar $translations[$i];

  # Terminate this word
  print ( ($i < scalar(@words_en) - 1) ? " " : ".\n" );
}
```

Comment: In fact the array `@words_en` is stored in an hash table like that : `$VAR1 = {
  'The cat eats the mouse' => {
    'words_en'    => ['The', 'cat', 'eats', 'the', 'mouse'],
    'score'       => '2.8',
    'translation' => 'Le chat mange la souris'
  }
};` How can I access the array in the hash table and print the same results ?

Comment: @chester You can assign with `my @words_en = (values %$hash)[0]->{words_en};`

Comment: Now the result of `print $words_en[$i];` is a ref `ARRAY(0x7fab408060e8)[].` Moreover, in my print I also need to associate the english sentence (with the translations) to the french sentence stored in the first hash (`'translation' => 'Le chat mange la souris'`).

Comment: @Chester Mc Allister you'll need to dereference  `(values %$hash)[0]->{words_en}; ` (*i.e.* assign it as @harvey suggests but to a scalar like `$words_en_ref`  and then wrap it with `@{ }`).  Or wrap the RHS to assign to an array.

Comment: @harvey the code in your comment assigns an array reference to an array ... typo?